# What is the conceptual opposite of hashing?

Tags: data-structures, hash

###### Context:

Let's say I perform hash the following strings with the respective results:

- "Hello World" -> 7
- "Hello Word"  -> 4
- "Hello World! Today is a new day to learn computer science!" -> 6

What I'm trying to show here is that hashing is "chaotic" where small changes to the input often lead to unpredictable differences in the output.

###### Question:

What is the conceptual opposite of the above, where small changes to the input lead to negligible differences in the output? Or, to state it differently, the input would need to be changed significantly in order for the output to change at all? To follow the same example above, a mapping like:

- "Hello World" -> 7
- "Hello Word"  -> 7
- "Hello World! Today is a new day to learn computer science!" -> 9

###### Why:

If such a concept exists, it would be quite useful for classification problems. The best guess I can come up with is "vectorization".

Comment: [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) might be an example.

Comment: That's unrelated to any existing uses of "vectorization".  Further, it's not a conceptual opposite of hashing.  It's still hashing, it's just a "poor hashing algorithm".

Comment: Are you looking for the term "Perceptual Hashing"?

Comment: @David yep! That term led me to the difference between Cryptographic Hashing (what I was thinking of in my example above) and Locality-Sensitive Hash, which looks like the answer I was looking for. Feel free to port your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like the search term you're looking for is [Perceptual Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing).

It's still *hashing*, but does indeed appear to be for a conceptually opposite end result.  I generally think of the differences as:

1. Cryptographic Hashing - Where slight changes to the input result in random, drastic changes to the output.  The goal is that it shouldn't be possible to determine any similarities in inputs based on the result, the result appears completely random.  Useful for storing passwords, for example.
2. Perceptual Hashing - Where slight changes to the input result in slight (or even no) changes to the output.  The goal is that it should be obvious based on the output if any two inputs were "similar enough" (changing one letter in text, or slightly altering a photo or audio file) for human needs.  Useful for finding instances of copyright infringement.  (And more nefarious things.  Digital forensics of underage pornography cases for example.)